# How to change direction in xelatex?

Tags: xetex, languages, persian

When I use fontspec package to type persian, it works but it's left align and 
paragraphs begin from left, same thing accure with enumerations and ... . How 
to get ride of this problem?

Note that I'm aware of bidi and xepersian packages and don't want to use them. 
Please give some solution that is more basic and not depend on special package 
(if possible!).

Comment: Can you provide a reason for *not* wanting to use `bidi` and `xepersian`? An independent solution to your objective may have to re-address all kinds of issues taken care of by these two packages...

Comment: First thanks for your attention. Because I may want to develop a new package! that's not all. xepersian does not work with beamer (but bidi works!) and I don't want to face with this type of issues when working with various package.

Comment: The more basic solution to not using `bidi` is to reimplement `bidi` yourself in every package you write. To do this I think you need to read the `bidi` code and make a really stripped down version that does what you want.

Comment: You should look into the new `bidipresentation` package.

Comment: bidipresentation has lots of problems. I think @AlanMunn was right. Thanks.

Comment: I’m  not surprised that `bidipresentation` has problems; it’s very new.  But submitting bug reports and patches seems more efficient than starting over from nothing.

Comment: You're right. But I don't think that developer of bidi(presentation) package can devote its time to this problems. But I agree with you almost every where!

Comment: Even if that's so, many time-constrained developers are happy to accept patches!

Answer (score 2):

Both in your question and answers, you have claimed things which are not true:

> xepersian does not work with beamer (but bidi works!) and I don't want
>   to face with this type of issues when working with various package.

This clearly shows that you have little knowledge (if any) about the matter. It is neither `xepersian` nor `bidi` fault that beamer does not work in RTL. It is an engine bug (`\special` in RTL mode). Both `bidi` and `xepersian` suffer because of the engine bug and the fact that you imagine `bidi` works with beamer is that the direction outside frames is RTL when you use `bidi` package. For the last part of your comment, again `xepersian` or `bidi` works with a lot of packages and there is not any need to do much really.

> bidipresentation has lots of problems.

What problems are you talking about? It is not that I think it is free of any bugs but people are using it every day and they are so far happy with the results.

> I don't think that developer of bidi(presentation) package can devote
>   its time to this problems

First you need to prove that indeed there are lots of problems (as you claimed) and then you need to prove that you have got in touch with me, told me about these problems but  I did not answer your query because I said that I do not have time. That is a lie! I have never got any email from anyone like you described.

Now let's answer your questions.

### RTL Paragraph Direction

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\TeXXeTstate=1
\everypar{\setbox0\lastbox\beginR\usebox0}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi dear Ms Khalighi.

Comment: Hi dear Ms Khalighi. I like you and your written packages so much and must thank you for your great job which is a great contribution to Iranian mathematics. Excuse me if there is some thing offensive in my question. Your right that I don't have lots of knowledge in TeX. I forget to say that your packages has lots of advantages and maybe you're right that reason of my bad experience with beamer lies in lake of knowledge, But I test it and right now I'm unable to exactly remember my problems (a gap between me and TeX caused by homework!). For presentation of my thesis I use luapersian!

Comment: I don't think the insult was necessary. Was it?